# Do I understand this proof for AoC $\implies$ well-ordering theorem correctly?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, well-orders

Am a real beginner in set-theory. I read that the Axiom of Choice (AoC) implies the Well-Ordering Theorem...

From what I understand, the gist of the proof is that given any set $X$, we can use AoC to well-order $X$ using induction. Namely, given any element $a_i \in X$ in the ordering, we can use the choice function $c$ (implied by AoC) to select $a_{i+1}=c(X-\bigcup_{j \leq i} a_j)$, and then extend the ordering to include $a_i \leq a_{i+1}$, and so on and so forth ...

But suppose that $X=\mathbb{R}$ ... if we try to well-order $\mathbb{R}$ using the proof above, up to what extent should we do the induction ?  Can we do the induction an uncountable number of times? --- up to say ... $2^{\omega}+1$ (where $\omega$ is the cardinal number of $\mathbb{N}$) i.e. to "exhaust" all of $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Also, you're not selecting from $X-\bigcup a_j$, instead you're selecting from $X-\{a_j\mid j\leq i\}$. And it's probably better to use $<$ here, to allow for limit steps as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, we're using recursion, rather than induction.

Secondly, the recursion can go as long as any ordinal $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha|=|\Bbb R|$, and there are a lot of these, at least $\aleph_2$, and in fact $(2^{\aleph_0})^+$ of them.

To see this in action, fix a well-ordering of $\Bbb N$ which is not of order type $\omega$, e.g., $\omega+1$. Then use this to define a choice function: $c(A)=\min A\setminus\{0\}$ or $0$ if $A=\{0\}$. If we use this as our choice function to well-order $\Bbb N$, we will end up with an order of type $\omega+1$. And the same happens with any other countably infinite ordinal.

So "how long"? Well, some ordinal of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, but there's a lot of them, so it's not possible to pre-determine which one. But that is exactly what makes transfinite recursion *trans-finite*. The ability to do it over very long well-orders.

(And as a side note, especially when we're dealing with recursion over the ordinals, it's better to use $\aleph$ notation to discuss cardinals, so you should write $2^{\aleph_0}$ rather than $2^\omega$. This way there is no chance of mistaking $2^\omega$ for *ordinal* exponentiation, which is just $\omega$ again.)

Comment: thanks for the clear answer ! just to clarify, it's more correct to use $\textit{recursion}$ than induction since induction can only be applied over $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: No, the general rule of thumb is that recursion is for constructions and inductions is for proofs. Transfinite induction is how we usually justify our transfinite recursion's construction (e.g. construct a maximal chain by transfinite recursion, and prove by induction that it no other element can be added to it). These go together quite closely, and it's easy to confuse, hence the rule of thumb at the start of this comment.